Question about invariant subspaces of C*-algebras.
Let $M$ be a subspace of some Hilbert space $H$ and let $U$ denote a $C*$-algebra contained in $L(H)$. Is it true that closure$[UM]$ is an invariant subspace of $U$?
I believe it is:
Assume $x \in$ closure$[UM]$. Then we can find sequences $\{T_n\}$ in $U$ and $\{y_n\}$ in $M$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}T_ny_n = x$. Therefore, for any $A \in U$ we have $Ax = A(\lim_{n \to \infty}T_ny_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} AT_ny_n$. However, $AT_n \in U$ because $U$ is an algebra
, and $x_n \in H$ by assumption. Therefore $\{AT_ny_n\}$ is a sequence in $UM$, hence, $Ax 
 \in$ closure$[AM]$ for any $A \in U$.
Is this proof correct? If not, can someone give an example of a subspace $M$ and $C*$-algebra $U$ where closure$[UM]$ is not an invariant subspace?

$UM$ is an invariant subspace for $U$ so is its closure, by the continuity of each element of $U.$

The result is right, though the proof is slightly off. $UM$ does not just consist of $Ty$ for $T \in U$ and $y \in M$. It consists of linear combinations of such things. So instead of $\lim_n T_ny_n = x$, you should have $\lim_n \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} T_{(n,i)}y_{(n,i)} = x$.

@David: do you have a trivial example where $UM$ is not a subspace? The easiest I can manage is $\dim U=\dim M=2$, but with $\dim H=9$.

@MartinArgerami $H=\mathbb{C}^3$, $U$ consists of diagonal operators $(a,a,b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, and $M={(c,d,d):c,d\in\mathbb{C}}$. Then the span of $UM$ is $\mathbb{C}^3$ as $(1,0,0)=(1,1,0)(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)(0,1,1)$, and $(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)(0,1,1)$. But $(1,0,1)\notin UM$, since $UM={(ac,ad,bd):a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}}$. If $(1,0,1)=(ac,ad,bd)$, then as $ad=0$, either $a=0$, in which case $ac=0\neq1$; or $d=0$, in which case $bd=0\neq1$, both contradictions.

This should be the smallest example. If either $U$ or $M$ has dimension 1, $UM$ is a subspace. So $U, M$ both have to have dimensions at least 2. A finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebra is unital, so as $U$ has dimension at least 2, its unity has to be a projection of rank at least 2. So if $H$ has dimension 2, $M$, having dimension at least 2, would equal $H$; and $U$ would contain $1_H$, then $H = M \subset UM$ and $UM$ is a subspace. So $H$ needs to have dimension at least 3.
